# Temporarily increase spacing between paragraphs in a quotation, and then put it back

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, parskip

I would like to add an extra blank line between paragraphs inside a quotation, but only inside of that quotation. I know you can do this using `\parskip`, but how do I restore the old value? I tried something like

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{quotation}
\setlength{\oldparskip}{\parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
This is some text.

This is more text.

This is yet another paragraph.
\end{quotation}
\end{figure}
\setlength{\parskip}{\oldparskip}
```

But this doesn't work; I get an error saying the command `\oldparskip` isn't defined. I basically want a temporary variable, unless there's a way of introducing some sort of environment that will automatically restore the old value when it finishes.

Comment: You have to catch the value of `parskip` before entering `quotation`. `oldparskip` is limited within the environment.

Comment: Apart from that, isn't environment `quote` qhat you are looking for?

Comment: not tried, but ... the `quotation` environment should be a "closed" environment, `figure` certainly is, and setting `\parskip` shouldn't be automatically global.  so try it without any mention of `\oldparskip`; just the one line resetting `\parskip` inside the quote may be sufficient.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: That works, thanks very much!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

setting `\parskip` shouldn't be automatically global, and if it's reset
within a "closed" environment, it should automatically revert to its
previous value when the environment is ended.

`quotation` should be a "closed" environment, and `figure` certainly is,
so the only adjustment needed here is the single

```
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
```

within the affected `quotation`.

Answer (score 1):

Barbara's answer is correct; a change to parskip will be local within the quote environment.

The actual problem of your example, though, is that you need `\newlength\oldparskip \setlength{\oldparskip}{\newparskip}` in the preamble, before you enter the quote environment.

(The Plain TeX way to do this would be `\let\oldparskip\parskip \parskip=\baselineskip .... \let\parskip\oldparskip` but there's no need to mix Plain synax with LaTeX here.)

If you always want a different parskip in an environment, you can use `\AtBeginEnvironment` from the `etoolbox` package, or more simply, you can just create a new environment that calls the standard one and adjusts the parskip:

```
\newenvironment{myquote}
    {\begin{quote}\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}}
    {\end{quote}}
```